# Terminology - What is an excursion?

Tags: terminology, noise

In a textbook I am reading on image sensors the author uses the term "excursion" in reference to noise in an image sensor. Quote from the book:

"Figure 7.26(a) presents a noise histogram for a sense capacitance that is allowed to vary by noise modulation. Note that the Gaussian distribution is skewed because of a changing sense capacitance. This output represents a measured result. The Fig. 7.26(b) histogram assumes that the noise ***excursions*** do not influence the sense capacitance and therefore exhibits a symmetrical response".

What does the term excursion mean in this context?  It seems that the author is simply referring to the fluctuations of the random noise in the sensor (i.e. excursions are synonymous with fluctuations). Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: That is how I would interpret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Excursions in this context merely means the extent of departure from constancy, in other words the expected extent of the noise. For example, from [the free medical dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/excursionexcursion): [ek-skur´zhun]
a range of movement regularly repeated in performance of a function, e.g., excursion of the jaws in mastication. adj., adj excur´sive.